# Python app on windows porting to linux

Tags: linux, windows, python-2.7, cross-platform

I am developing an python application in windows as of now which uses windows specific libraries such as win32api, win32com etc.
The app runs well in windows.
Now I want to port the same app to linux. And by obvious reasons I am getting the below error.

```
user@userdomain$ python run_app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "run_app.py", line 15, in <module>
    import win32api
ImportError: No module named win32api
```

Now I want to know:
What is the good programming way to make my app run on both linux and windows.
I found out to check the OS running in the begging with code `os.name` and run the below code in every instance.

```
if os.name == 'nt'
    import win32api
    import win32com
else:
    import linux related apis
```

Is this a good way? I am afraid my code will be clumsy with this approach.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using PyQt.
Qt is a cross-platform framework for among others GUIs. 

 Works excellent. It's worth of try. You don't even care of host OS recognition. Just write one code and it runs the same way on Widnows and Linux.

Besides that there is also PyWX.